# Stock update trigger on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm unfamiliar with PostgreSQL triggers because I know they work a bit differently than other plsql triggers. I have two tables: inventory and package that look the following way:

```
inventory(idinv(PK),available_quantity,total_quantity)

package(idpackage(PK),idinv(PK/FK),assigned_quantity,delivered_quantity,status)
```

Now, I need to create two triggers.

1. A trigger that substracts the assigned_quantity on package (when assigned_quantity is updated) from the available_quantity on inventory.
2. A trigger that substracts the delivered_quantity on package (when status on package is updated to "DELIVERED") from the total_quantity on inventory.

I have no idea how to write these triggers.

Comment: Does this [PostgreSQL Trigger Tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/) help?

Comment: It is better to read the PostgreSQL documentation, which describes triggers and PL/pgSQL quite well.